# shared object error when using binary on different machine

Tags: c++, linker, compilation, portability

How can I avoid this? I have a pretty simple c++ program compiled on a ubuntu box. When I move it over to red hat and try to execute it I get an error something like:

```
cannot find shared object stdlibc++5.so
```

How does commercial software get around this, the stdlib installed on users machines is going to vary a lot. Is there some flag I need to be using when  I compile?

Comment: Commercial software has to provide multiple binaries that are linked against the prevailing versions of the C and C++ libraries that are found in supported distributions. You *could* link statically, but that's fairly inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to recompile it again because:

1. OS is different [Ubuntu and Red Hat]
2. The location of libraries might be different. Also there are chances (though very 
   minute) that stdc++ library is not present at all.
3. In commercial software employing compiled languages like C/C++ , the applications are 
   deployed on the same OS (both development and production..as far as I know) and usually , 
   the library locations are also consistent

So, please check if you are able to compile your C++ code (may be hello world) and compile your code again.

Answer (score 1):

There could be any number of reasons for this; for all you know, the
target machine may not have installed g++ and its libraries.  The only
real solution is to statically link the standard C++ library, using the
`-static-libstdc++` option.